# How to change logic of autoupdater?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I came up with the following

1. There are two projects in Solution (the updater and the program itself)
2. the updater runs, verifies the version on the server if there is a new version downloads the archive with the files of the new program
3. Unzip it to the program folder, launch the main application, delete the archive and close

Here, in paragraph 3, there is confusion. Because on the Internet, in the examples, they show how to update only the exe file. And I need to copy files from the archive to it. And if you just copy and replace, then something that was removed in If you delete the folder and create a new version, then delete and update. It only comes to the installer to install in a different place and not in the folder with the main program, but this option is not very good for me.

Comment: You started the question from the end. You assume that an installer only needs to unzip some stuff. Or that you can just delete folders without paying attention to what's in them - including deleting other applications' files or user documents. That's not how installers on Windows work. There's a very real reason Windows Installer, ClickOnce or Chocolatey work they way they do. Don't reinvent the wheel and use one of the existing deployment technologies

Comment: As for updating a) Clickonce, Windows Store applications and Chocolatey packages already do this properly. b) The thing you need to download and execute is the installer. The installer will take care of updating/replacing files in a safe way